# Camera.open() returns NULL Android development

Tags: android, camera

I am following the tutorial for building a camera app http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html and I am my call to Camera.open() returns null. I've declared the permission in the manifest and I tried both on the emulator and a xyboard and I am still getting null. Does anyone know any quick hints?

```
Camera c = null;
try
{
    c = Camera.open()
}
catch(Exeption e)
{

}
return c;
```

Keep in mind, I am not throwing an exception, I am simply getting NULL back.

Comment: Check logcat, SOMETHING is happening. Also camera implementation is different for different devices and OS levels, need more information.

Answer (score 4):

That's because [it's not supposed to throw an exception](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28%29).  It returns `null` when no *back*-facing camera is found:

> Creates a new Camera object to access the first back-facing camera on the device. If the device does not have a back-facing camera, this returns null.

You may be trying to access a *front*-facing camera, in which case you probably want to use `open(int cameraId)`.  (See the other answer for an example of using it)

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a really great tutorial for working with the android camera](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html)
You'll notice thru out the code there are toasts/alerts that will help guide you to what is happening

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this working, I had to use the Camera.open(0) which meant that I had to change the API level in the manifest from 8 to 9. I am now getting an Error 100 though...